# How to define routes that include the current user with Iron Router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm fairly new to Meteor and Iron Router and I'm trying to create a route that looks like this '/users/hippomoe/bookmarks/Kj6ecNk7DeW7PmmGA' where hippomoe would be the current logged in user and Kj6ecNk7DeW7PmmGA would be the id of a bookmark. Some of the things that I've tried were to add a handlebars helper that would provide the username

```
bookmark: function() {
    return {
        _id: this._id,
        user: Meteor.user().username
    };
}
```

and I also tried defining user: Meteor.user().username in the data context within the RouteController definition. In both instances I get the following error: "You called Route.prototype.resolve with a missing parameter. "user" not found in params"

I've tried finding an example that illustrates this type of route (which I assume would be common). The other questions that I have seen on StackOverflow related to this were about getting the user associated with a particular document and not the current user that is logged in.

It seems that I missing something simple. Can someone provide/point me to a simple example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having difficulty understanding why you would need such a route. If you already know the name of the logged in user, why would you need to have it once more in the route? Or is this meant to be server-side? In that case, please show your routes.

Otherwise, does this not work:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('postShow', {
    path: '/users/:ignoreme/bookmarks/_id',
    data: function () {
      var params = this.params;
      var user = Meteor.user().username;
      if (user == params.ignoreme) {
          ...
      } else {
          return "something went wrong";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This is just to allow the url pattern you want, but again, I don't see why you wouldn't just use a URL /user/bookmarks or similar and then change the logic to depend on Meteor.user().

Comment: The route '/users/hippomoe/bookmarks/_id' is I suppose a similar structure idea as what stackoverflow has with their '/users/1766665/hippomoe' URL structure when clicking on the reputation/badges icon at the top. I don't have much experience with URL design, so I could be off base with this type of URL structure and my question may be unclear.

Comment: Regarding URL design, the question is whether your bookmarks can be viewed by others.  In StackOverflow, there are publicly viewable profile pages so they need a URL to reference them.  The user Id is actually the only required part ('/users/1766665/') which is a good design because it allows users to change their usernames if needed.  In your app, if users are only allowed to view their own information then you wouldn't need the id in the url.

Comment: @alanning Using an id in the url instead of the username provides flexibility that I had not thought about. Other users would be able to view publicly shared bookmarks on the users bookmarks page.

Answer (score 0):

The handlebars helper that I had written in my question

```
bookmark: function() {
    return {
        _id: this._id,
        user: Meteor.user().username
    };
}
```

would have worked if I would have specified the pathFor syntax correctly. My pathFor should have looked like this

```
{{pathFor 'saveBookmark' bookmark}}
```

I had inadvertently left off bookmark!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a ':' before _id, try this:

```
path: '/users/:ignoreme/bookmarks/:_id',
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the example route well. I mixed a specific URL example with how the paramterized version would appear in my routes. I changed the example in my question. I didn't forget the ':' in my route. I did however did not express the pathFor correctly in my HTML.